# Showing $\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{2t} \mathrm{d}x$ concentrates around $\frac{1}{2t}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we have the following integral for $t>0$

$$f(t)=\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{2t} \mathrm{d}x$$

I'm interested in approximating it by integrating over a smaller interval $(a,b)$

$$f(t)\approx \int_a^b x(1-x)^{2t} \mathrm{d}x$$

Where $a$ is chosen so that the mass discarded on the left is at most $0.005 f(t)$, and $b$ is chosen so that the mass discarded on the right is at most $0.005 f(t)$.

In numerical simulations, $a$ and $b$ decay in proportion to $1/t$, what is the easiest way of showing this?

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-integration-bounds.nb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from @Ace's answer, you want to find, for a given value of $t$, the zero of function
$$f(a)=(1-a)^{2 t+1}\, (a(2 t+1)+1)-\frac{199}{200}=0$$ and we know that $a\ll 1$.

This being a polynomial of degree $2(t+1)$ in $a$, the only hope is *approximation*.

Expand $f(a)$ as a Taylor series around $a=0$ (say to $O(a^4)$) and then power series reversion to obtain
$$a=\frac{\sqrt{f(a)+\frac{1}{200}}}{\sqrt{(t+1) (2 t+1)}}+\frac{2 \left(f(a)+\frac{1}{200}\right) t}{3 (t+1) (2 t+1)}+\frac{\left(f(a)+\frac{1}{200}\right)^{3/2} t (22 t+9)}{36 ((t+1) (2 t+1))^{3/2}}+\cdots$$

Now, remember that we need $f(a)=0$; so, the estimate of $a$.

$$a\sim \frac{t \left(14422 \sqrt{2} t+480 \sqrt{(t+1) (2 t+1)}+21609
   \sqrt{2}\right)+7200 \sqrt{2}}{144000 ((t+1) (2 t+1))^{3/2}}$$ which seems to be acceptable
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
t & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
  5 & 0.00896731 &  0.00896788 \\
 10 & 0.00480313 &  0.00480347 \\
 15 & 0.00328033 &  0.00328058 \\
 20 & 0.00249073 &  0.00249092 \\
 25 & 0.00200753 &  0.00200768 \\
 30 & 0.00168135 &  0.00168148 \\
 35 & 0.00144635 &  0.00144647 \\
 40 & 0.00126899 &  0.00126909 \\
 45 & 0.00113038 &  0.00113047 \\
 50 & 0.00101906 &  0.00101914 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For very large values of $t$, expanding again the estimate
$$a \sim \frac{7451}{144000 t}-\frac{2569}{64000
   t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)$$ which is "not far" from $\frac 1{20\,t}$

**Edit**

Since in comments, you mention Lambert function, you are looking for the inverse of
$$2t+1=-\frac 1 a +\frac 1{\log(1-a)}W_{-1}\left(\frac {199}{200}\frac{\log (1-a)}{a}(1-a)^{\frac{1}{a}}\right)$$ Limiting the expansion to first order (and it is a good approximation)
$$a \sim \frac{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{199}{200 e}\right)+1}{-(2t+1)+\frac{1}{2}
   W_{-1}\left(-\frac{199}{200 e}\right)}$$

Making the numbers rational
$$a \sim \frac{3}{58\, t+45}$$

Using one more term in the expansion, using $w=W_{-1}\left(-\frac{199}{200 e}\right) \sim -\frac{725}{657}$,

$$a=-\frac{w+1}{(2t+1)}-\frac{w (w+1)}{2 (2t+1)^2}+\frac{w \left(-4   w^2+w+5\right)}{24(2t+1)^3}+\cdots$$

Comment: Interesting! I also obtained very accurate approximation by taking 2 term Taylor expansion of the left tail in terms of $a$ and solving for $t$, $$a\approx \sqrt{\frac{0.005}{2 t^2+3 t+1}}$$ . However, this approach to solve for $b$ gave me something inaccurate

Comment: Some CAS assisted manipulation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286794/217)  gives the following explicit solution for $$b=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{W_{-1}\left(\frac{(1-t)^{1/t} \epsilon  \log (1-t)}{t}\right)}{\log (1-t)}-\frac{1}{t}-1\right)$$ where $\epsilon=0.005$

Answer (score 1):

The equations to solve $a$ and $b$ can be derived. For example
$$f(t)=\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{2t} \mathrm{d}x
=\frac1{2(t+1)(2t+1)}$$
$$f_a(t)=\int_0^a x(1-x)^{2t} \mathrm{d}x
=\frac{1-(1-a)^{2t+1}}{2t+1}- \frac{1-(1-a)^{2t+2}}{2t+2}$$
Then, set
$$\frac{f_a(t)}{f(t)}=0.005$$
and solve for $a$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: Solving it seems tricky (in terms of Lambert W perhaps?) The interesting part is why the solution is proportional to 1/t?

Answer (score 1):

I jumped over from the question on the [mathematica stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286786/asymptotic-inversion-of-ft-root1-y2-t1-2-t-yy1-1-1000/286817#286817)
Starting with

$f_a(a) = (1-a)^{2t+1}(a(2t+1)+1)-\frac{199}{200}$

observe (for some constant $k$)

$f_a(\frac{k}{t}) = -\frac{199}{200} + (1-\frac{k}{t})^{2t+1} (1 + \frac{k(1+2t)}{t})$

In the limit $t->\infty$,

$L(k) =\mathrm{lim}_{t->\infty}f_a(\frac{k}{t}) = -\frac{199}{200}+e^{-2k} (1+2k)$

Finding the root of $L(k)$ produces two constant real solutions for large $t$ (I used Mathematica to find the roots):

$L(k)=0 $

$k_1->\frac{1}{2}\left(-1-W_0(-\frac{199}{200e})\right),\\ k_2->\frac{1}{2}\left(-1-W_{-1}(-\frac{199}{200e})\right)$

Where $W_k$ is the k-th branch of the Lambert $W$ function.

The solutions can also be approximated as

$k_1 -> -0.048406,\\ k_2 -> 0.0517473$

since the domain of a is $0<a<1$ and we constructed our solution to look like $a=k/t$, we know $0<k<t$ for $t>0$, so we select only the positive solution $k_2->\frac{1}{2}\left(-1-W_{-1}(-\frac{199}{200e})\right) \sim 0.0517473 $

so for large $t$

$f_a(a) = (1-a)^{2t+1}(a(2t+1)+1)-\frac{199}{200}=0$

has a solution $a = \frac{k_2}{t}$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. BTW, using notation of this question, your answer gives the value of $b$. $a$ is actually easier -- doing 2 term Taylor series expansion gave almost perfect fit with this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thx6B.png)

Comment: Ah yes I see I think I should've used 1/200 instead of 199/200. And yes that is a much simpler solution